# Hackeo a mi base de datos - Cambio de contraseña admin

Tags: php, base-de-datos, seguridad

La página problemática era la página de restablecimiento de contraseña, la cual he modificado desde entonces para mostrar un mensaje de mantenimiento mientras averiguamos dónde están los agujeros.

Los piratas informáticos del rescate lograron solicitar un restablecimiento de contraseña a cualquier cuenta y luego, sin necesidad del enlace de correo electrónico y la tecla para hacer clic se las arreglaron para cambiar la contraseña.

Desconozco como pueden haber cambiado la contraseña sin tener que acceder al email de verificación.

- Fichero 1: https://pastebin.com/DtGsbPtz
- Fichero 2: https://pastebin.com/1RJMpVTc

Parece que alguien emite una contraseña de reinicio, y sin acceso al correo electrónico de los usuarios, todavía puede restablecer la contraseña.

Es un reinicio basado en una clave token estándar utilizando:

```
$token = bin2hex (random_bytes (32));
```

Luego, cuando el usuario haga clic en el enlace de restablecimiento, la base de datos se emparejará con el token.

No se ha agregado nada por lo que sé, es un script php7 estándar sin funcionalidad adicional de php.

No puedo imaginar cómo alguien podría ejecutar cualquier código arbitrario ya que es una contraseña de restablecimiento estándar.

El formulario de reinicio se refiere a una tabla en la base de datos la tabla de usuarios editado y cuando crea la clave, entonces actualiza ese usuario con dicha clave cuando el usuario recibe el correo electrónico para restablecer su contraseña, se le da un enlace que coincide con la clave de ese miembro que les permite cambiar su contraseña entonces la forma y su contraparte usa una tabla y 3 columnas:

- Identificación
- contraseña
- restablecimientoCompleto

Comment: Por desgracia con sólo esos dos archivos no es posible averiguar el vector de ataque. Ten en cuenta que cualquier script PHP que tenga un agujero de seguridad podría ser explotado para múltiples vectores de entrada como subir un script PHP con una shell, o inyección SQL desde otro script que no es ninguno de los relacionados con el login o cambio de contraseña.

Comment: Que información mas sería necesaria?

Comment: Para un análisis forense también se necesitarían los logs de acceso del servidor para saber si llegaron a usar el formulario de envío del token o no o, al menos, hacerse una idea de qué ruta tomaron para realizar el ataque. Es probable que esas dos páginas no tengan nada que ver con el ataque. En cuanto alguna página permita fuga de información es posible que el contenido del token de restablecimiento pudiera obtenerse a partir del agujero de otro script. También hay posibilidad de que el problema esté en la subida de archivos de alguna otra zona de la web, que permita la subida de scripts.

Comment: @david lamentablemente tu sitio tiene una superficie de ataque **e-nor-me**. Me parece que el ataque pudo haber venido por cualquier otro lado. Por ejemplo directo a phpMyAdmin, al servidor de correo, SSH, FTP, la base de datos, Lethe Mailing list, etc. Mi sugerencia es reducir la superficie, ya que tienes demasiados puntos de vulnerabilidad.  Me parece que tu servidor incluso acepta requests del tipo **PUT**

Comment: Es posible que tengas mejor respuesta si posteas tu pregunta en https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: La seguridad del servidor no se ha comprometido. Hay otros 15 sitios web ejecutándose en el servidor sin problemas. SSH informa las direcciones IP exactas de todos los que han iniciado sesión con éxito y solo mi IP ha iniciado sesión exitosamente porque no le doy a muchas personas acceso a ssh. Igualmente no se ha comprimizado ninguna otra base de datos. ¿Qué archivos de registro le gustaría ver? Claramente van a haber docenas de varios archivos de registro en un sistema ubuntu. Que debo hacer?

Comment: Aqui podeis ver los logs; http://thedownliner.com/log.txt
El servidor si que tiene habilitado los puts

Comment: tal vez relacionado: https://www.skeletonscribe.net/2013/05/practical-http-host-header-attacks.html